# Exception when trying to copy the data into a char pointer value

Tags: c, string, exception, char, append

I am a newbie to C. I have this print statement where a particular values gets printed. I need to copy this value into a String. But when I try to copy it, I am getting the below shown exception.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCF01CB20A (msvcr120d.dll) in RFIDTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000E200.
```

Shown below is the print statement, the output of which I need to put into a variable.

```
printf("%04X", (((epc[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((epc[i] & 0xFF) << 8)));
```

Show below is how I tried to get it into a variable and append it.

```
strcat(("%04X", (((epc[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((epc[i] & 0xFF) << 8))),strData);
```

My complete method is as follows.

```
char* ipj_util_print_epc(uint16_t* epc, int len, bool little_endian)
{
char * strData="";
int i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    /* Print hyphen every two bytes */
    if (i % 1 == 0 && i > 0)
    {
        printf("-");
        strcat("-",strData);
    }
    /* Print one byte at a time */
    if (little_endian)
    {
        printf("%04X", (((epc[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((epc[i] & 0xFF) << 8)));
        strcat(("%04X", (((epc[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((epc[i] & 0xFF) << 8))),strData);
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(("%04X", epc[i]),strData);
        printf("%04X", epc[i]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
return strData;
}
```

If I am doing it wrong then how can I get these values that are getting printed into a variable?

Comment: how can some int % 1 ever be != 0 ?

Comment: Yes thanks for spotting it out. Please help me with this exception :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining suggestions from others, your function should be:

```
char* ipj_util_print_epc(uint16_t* epc, int len, bool little_endian)
{
    char *strData = malloc(len*4+(len+1)/2+1);  // 4 chars per uint16, hyphens and terminating \0
    int i;
    char *bufp= strData;
    strData[0]= '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        /* Print hyphen every two bytes */
        if (i % 2 == 0 && i > 0)
        {
            printf("-");
            strcat(bufp,"-");
            bufp++;
        }
        /* Print one byte at a time */
        if (little_endian)
        {
            printf("%04X", (((epc[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((epc[i] & 0xFF) << 8)));
            bufp += sprintf(bufp,"%04X", (((epc[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((epc[i] & 0xFF) << 8))));
        }
        else
        {
            bufp += sprintf(bufp,"%04X", epc[i]));
            printf("%04X", epc[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return strData;
}
```

Comment: you mixed the last 2 arguments in the sprintf and it is undefined behaviour if a source and the destination buffer overlap.

Comment: @mch, thanks for spotting the error in sprintf aerguments. Fixed it. Though source and destination overlap, the net effect is appending, or actually copying strData onto itself and then appending.

Comment: To satisfy any UB gurus, I ammended the solution to avoid source and destination of sprintf to overlap.

Comment: Still doesn't help. At the point of the declaration of strData, char *strData = malloc(len * 4 + (len + 1) / 2 + 1); it says <Error reading characters of string> :(

Comment: I had to set it to empty string. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: @PaulOgilvie after malloc should I clear the memory? if so how? Please advice.

Comment: @mayooran You return `strData` from this function , so you need to `free` it in calling function .

Comment: @ameyCU the returbed strData is a local variable. So I will not be having access to that variable in the calling function. How can I free it in there? :(

Comment: @mayooran How do you call your function ?

Comment: char * strData2 = ""; strData2 = ipj_util_print_epc((uint16_t*)tag_operation_report->tag.epc.bytes,(int)tag_operation_report->tag.epc.size/2,true); is how I am calling the function we have been discussing.

Answer (score 2):

```
 strcat("-",strData);
```

`strcat` appends second string to first one.

Here you try to modify string literal `"-"` , which is constant. Maybe you want to add `-` to `strData` , then it should be first argument to `strcat`.

And also you have declared `strData` as -

```
char * strData="";
```

It is also a string literal. So you need to do this , where you will be albe to modify its contents-

```
char * strData;
strData=malloc(len);                // any desired length
```

Comment: Even after changing the elements like, strcat(strData,"-"); and strcat(strData,("%04X", (((epc[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((epc[i] & 0xFF) << 8)))); I am still getting the error.

Comment: @mayooran Also you need to allocate memory to `strData`, before `strcat` .

Comment: I have added malloc as well now. Still getting the error. Is it really possible to append to char * ? or is it a char array that I need?

Comment: @mayooran you cannot do `strcat(strData,("%04X", (((epc[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((epc[i] & 0xFF) << 8))));`, you have to use `sprintf`.

Comment: @mayooran In your `strcat` you also , pass format specifier , why ?

Comment: `strcat` is not `sprintf`. Use `sprintf` if you need to format the result.

Comment: @ameyCU even after changing it as sprintf, I am getting the same error